# Which CDN does Netflix and Hulu use and how can they offer unlimited streaming for $10 per month?

Tags: streaming, cdn, smoothing, netflix

Do anybody know which CDN Netflix and Hulu use for hosting their content and what they are paying for traffic/streaming costs?

(meaning; how can they possibly offer unlimited streaming for about $10 per month when considering all the streaming traffic costs I would think that they have to pay?)

Also, is it possible to set up Silverlight Smooth Streaming via Amazon CloudFront?

--

We want to offer our clients the ability to sell their full-length movies in Silverlight Smooth Streaming HD 720p format.

One full length movie at 3 Mbps may be around 1.8 GB and our clients wants to sell rental for e.g. $5 for 48 hours access.

The biggest CDNs are quoting prices in the $0.50 (and more) per GB traffic pricing range.

That means that the traffic costs for streaming the movie only once may be around 20% of the cost of the movie and additional views by the same user will make the traffic cost eat almost the whole (or even more) of the cost of the movie very quickly, making the business model essentially useless.

Comment: This research paper reverse-engineered the architectures of these streaming platforms and their CDN selection strategies - https://www.moritzsteiner.de/papers/netflix-hulu.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Hulu's [website](http://www.hulu.com/about/media_faq#technology)

> Who are some of Hulu’s top technology
>   partners? Hulu leverages several
>   technology partners to help provide a
>   high-quality and trusted service for
>   our users including Akamai, who
>   manages our content delivery network
>   (CDN), and Adobe who is Hulu’s video
>   player platform provider.

It appears Netflix also use [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/) for 51% of their traffic for a reported $0.015 per GB (sources [here](http://blog.streamingmedia.com/the_business_of_online_vi/2010/03/akamai-now-the-primary-cdn-for-netflix-but-at-a-very-low-price.html) and [here](http://seekingalpha.com/article/191356-akamai-becoming-primary-cdn-for-netflix-but-at-a-very-low-price)).

Comment: wow, what a discount for the big boys 50 > 1.5 cents.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how the little guys like us can get started selling relatively few (compared to the big boys) 2 GB 720p movies when their quotes are as high as they are. (edit: removed first sentence after actually reading the article)

Comment: Akamai doesn't want small-shop customers; that's not their business model (small customers cost too much to service with salespeople, contracts, etc.). At the lower end, you can get LimeLight's CDN for $.22/GB pay-as-you go via Rackspace. Amazon's CloudFront is $.15, Microsoft's is about the same, and others go even lower (I think I saw $.039 for one). I suggest you look down-market while you're starting out, and only talk with Akamai when you need the scale they can offer and can push amounts of traffic that will get you big discounts of their "starter" pricing.

Comment: This answer was written five years ago.  Any updates now on how Netflix handles its streaming?  They definitely use AWS in parts of their stack, but does that also include their CDN?  https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/netflix/

Answer (score 2):

Netflix uses Akamai.  From my caps:

`Internet Protocol, Src: a224.w31.akamai.net (168.143.241.24), Dst: 192.168.2.4 (192.168.2.4)`

Comment: Thanks Chris, I appreciate it. However I was also more specifically interested in what they are paying for traffic so I found ghoppe's answer and the article to have more of the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to get the same price is find a newer rep and play the cdns against each other.  You should get .05/GB.  It has become a commodity.